# How do I get my contact form to work with angularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to integrate AngularJS with my contact form. When I test to see if the validation works or the warning message will fire if the form is empty, it submits, but it appears to just refresh the browser.

This is my HTML:

```
<form ng-controller="ContactController" ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group uk-form-row" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputName.$invalid && submitted }">
    <label for="inputName" class="uk-form-label control-label">Your Name</label>
           <div class="uk-form-controls">
               <input ng-model="formData.inputName" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name" class=" form-control uk-width-1-1" id="inputName" name="inputName" required>
           </div>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group uk-form-row" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="uk-form-label control-label">Your Email!</label>
             <div class="uk-form-controls">
             <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control uk-width-1-1" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Please enter your email" required>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group uk-form-row" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputSubject.$invalid && submitted }">
       <label for="inputSubject" class="uk-form-label control-label">Subject</label>
       <div class="uk-form-controls">
        <input ng-model="formData.inputSubject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" required>
       </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group uk-form-row" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
     <label for="inputMessage" class="uk-form-label control-label">Message</label>
     <div class="uk-form-controls">
     <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" class="form-control" cols="100" rows="9" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="uk-form-row">
     <div class="uk-form-controls">
           <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled">Submit</button>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="uk-form-row">
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
           <p ng-class="result" style=" font-weight:bold; padding: 15px; margin: 0;">{{ resultMessage }}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS (angular):

```
rustyApp.controller('ContactController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; led = false;
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
         if (contactform.$valid) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '../partials/mailer.php',
            data: $.param($scope.formData), //param method from jQuery
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            } 
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-success';
                if ($scope.result === 'bg-success') {
                    $scope.class = "bg-success";
                }
                // if($scope.result){setTimeout(window.location.reload(true),4000);}
                if ($scope.result) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.reload(true)
                    }, 4000);
                }
            } else {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
            }
        });
    } else {
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
        if ($scope.submitButtonDisabled) {
            $scope.class = "bg-danger";
        }
        $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed Please fill out all the fields.';
        $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
    }
}
});
```

**UPDATE Dec 15th 7:20pm**

This is the error I get now after I followed Sunil's recommendations:

[image]

**UPDATE Dec 16th 7:12pm**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want AngularJS to submit the form, you should not use the `action` attribute on the `<form>` tag (the `method` attribute is also not needed). This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action) for the `form` directive.

There's a lot of other code there, so I may have missed other things that might be issues. But the presence of the action attribute (I'm assuming even though it is empty) is what is causing the form to be submitted by the browser.

Comment: That seemed to work; THANKS! I now get the prompts (validations) to kick in,  and the page doesn't refresh! However I need to get it to submit, it just remains in that state...So I guess I am missing something to process the form?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz Is the form valid when you submit? Your code looks ok on the surface. You might try using the shortcut method [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) and just pass the URL and the post data only. I am wondering if you really need to use that jQuery `param` function. Also, you may not need to set the content type header either (unless it's required by your server). Generally, Angular is pretty good about handling common scenarios for you.

Comment: Interesting, I opened up dev tools, and got the error above, in the update. But once I remove the `param` function I get..`app.js:49457 Object {success: false, message: "Please fill out the form completely."}`

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz One thing you can do to see what is invalid in the form is `console.log(contactform);` Inspect that object in the dev tools, specifically looking at the `$error` property.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it looks like I get an `Object` as a value to the `$error` property that i got back. And that `$error` seems to have two properties `required` which has a value of `Array[4] and '__proto__': which has a `Object` as a value. I included a snapshot above.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz The $error object has a property for all of the validations that failed. So in your case, it's saying that 4 fields failed the "required" validation.

Comment: But isn't that correct? I do want those fields to be validated?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz I'm not sure if we're in agreement or not :) When the form is valid, the $error object won't have any properties on it. So if `$error.required` is defined, it means that fields contained in `$error.required` array are failing the required validation. If those fields are truly empty, then yes, it's correct b/c your code won't submit the form unless it's valid.